# How to use built in typescript definitions of a npm package (firebase in particular)

Tags: typescript, firebase, typescript-typings, firebaseui

I am writing a web app in typescript for firebase. But i can't get the imports working for firebaseui and firebase itself.
This is a general problem of mine that I was never able to import typedefinitions that are shipped with a library whithout a @types package. There seems something wrong with my setup but I can't find the point where I am taking the wrong turn.

I have just installed "firebaseui" via npm, and try to use it as in the documentation of firebase but I can't get the import for firebaseui and firebase.auth right. Visual Studio Code also does not offer imports for that.

I would write the imports to look like this:

```
import { firebase } from 'firebase';
import { firebaseui } from 'firebaseui';
```

I have also seen other using this which also does not work

```
import { firebase, firebaseui } from 'firebase';
```

The compiler can't find the module 'firebase'. It seems like the typings from within the package are not picked up.

My tsconfig.json looks like that:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    }
}
```

My TSC version is 7.15.1

I have found this question but there is no explanation and it doesn't work either.
[How to get TypeScript to recognize firebase import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572826/how-to-get-typescript-to-recognize-firebase-import)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed my own mistake. I followed the official docs on the firebase website, the github page of the package has maybe more up to date or more acurate(?) docs
firebaseui has to imported as:

```
import firebaseui from 'firebaseui';
```

without the curly brackets.

Firebase is tucked away in a subfolder of firebase:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```

Found the solution on the github page of the package where they use import instead of require to show the correct pathes.
https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web